# GADS does not remove user from GoogleApps groups when remove them from AD groups

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, google-apps

I'm trying to sync our Active Directory groups membership to Google Apps groups using GADS. For the new user in a group (A), It works OK and was added to the Google Groups. But, when I remove that user from A group in Active Directory and run the GADS sync, that user is still stay in the A group in GoogleApps.

Am I missing something or Is there anything wrong with the GADS app? I am using Google Apps Directory Sync Version 4.2.1 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

Thanks,

Trinh

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, I recommend updating to the latest GADS, 4.3.2.

Once you've done that, if you can reproduce the issue, you'll want to generate trace level logs and search for the user in question. I also recommend renaming your .log file so it'll only include one sync. This will give you more information on why it's not being removed.

The logs might have too much information for you to want to sanitize and post publicly. I would recommend opening a Google case w/ the .log file and your XML. Google Support might also require and LDIF of your LDAP but not always.

Comment: I did upgrade to GADS 4.3.2 but the issue's still there. I'm contacting Google support.

Answer (score 0):

I end up answering the question myself by writing a python script:

1. Search for all users in AD groups which you want to sync to Google:

http://www.dangtrinh.com/2016/07/get-all-ms-active-directory-group.html

2. Search for all users in Google groups:

http://www.dangtrinh.com/2016/07/get-google-group-members-using-gam-and.html

3. Compare two lists and delete Google Group members that does not appears in AD's counter part.

Here is the working script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import shlex, subprocess
import sys
# ad_utils.py: http://www.dangtrinh.com/2016/07/get-all-ms-active-directory-group.html
import ad_utils


GADMIN_ACCOUNT = '<your google apps administrator email>'
GAM_PATH = '/path/to/your/gam.py'
GOOGLE_GROUPS = {
    '<group name>': 'group email',
...
}


def get_group_members(group_email, gam_path=GAM_PATH):

    cmd = 'python %s print group-members group %s' % (gam_path, group_email)
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        cmd = 'gam print group-members group %s' % (group_email)

    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()

    members = []
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        if out:
            out = out.split('\n')
            for i in range(1, len(out)):
                row = out[i].split(',')
                if len(row) >= 3:
                    if row[2].lower() != GADMIN_ACCOUNT: # exclude gadmin account
                        members.append(row[2].lower())
    return members


def del_group_member(group_email, member_email, gam_path=GAM_PATH):

    cmd = 'python %s update group %s remove user %s' % (gam_path, group_email, member_email)
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        cmd = 'gam update group %s remove user %s' % (group_email, member_email)

    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()

    return proc.returncode, out, err


def sync_ad_gapps_group_members(group_name, group_email, ad_conn, dry_run=False):
    ad_members = ad_utils.get_group_members(group_name, ad_conn)
    if ad_members:
        googlegroup_members = get_group_members(group_email)
        for guser in googlegroup_members:
            if guser not in ad_members:
                print "=== %s not active in AD" % guser
                if dry_run:
                    pass
                else:
                    del_group_member(group_email, guser)


def sync_ad_gapps_groups(dry_run=False):
    ad_conn, ad_result = ad_utils.ad_auth()
    if ad_result:
        for gname, gemail in GOOGLE_GROUPS.iteritems():
            print "\n+++ Syncing group %s" % gname
            sync_ad_gapps_group_members(gname, gemail, ad_conn, dry_run)
    else:
        print "Fail!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dry_run = False
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        dry_run = bool(sys.argv[1])

    if dry_run:
        print "=== Running Google Apps Groups sync in dry-run mode"

    print "==== Dry running: %s" % dry_run

    sync_ad_gapps_groups(dry_run)
```

**Usage:**

```
$ python google_groups_ad_sync.py [dry_run]
```

You can set up a scheduled task that runs this script after GADS.